# Blank Normal Map for simple Voronoi Texture+bump

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I am trying to generate a normal map from voronoi texture + bump but its resulting in blank normal map. I am just a beginner in blender and I am pretty sure am missing out on some of the basic things here but I can't figure it out for 2 days.

Left one is the source for baking normal map. But as you can see its blank with no details.
[image: 01]

Here is my source object material nodes:
[image]

Here is the destination object material nodes:
[image]

Also the its unwrapped
[image]

Here are the bake settings in render section

[image]

But you can see the Normal Map is completely empty
[image]

I used an HDR image for environment texture here also its latest Blender version 3.3 just incase. I tried many things but can't figure out what am I doin wrong here. I need guidance toward the right workflow to do this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: maybe put the small sphere inside the big one and disable the Bake > Cage option if you don't use any cage?

Comment: There's a quick tutorial on baking normal maps [here](https://youtu.be/dPbrhqqrZck?list=PLsGl9GczcgBvJPh7D_ITafvmTW7ZzQTEr) which might help.

Comment: @moonboots both are equal spheres that just perspective. I just tried baking without cage option its still the same.

Comment: could you please share your file?

Comment: @moonboots here is the file https://www.dropbox.com/s/f17pclc2zjjfztb/learn.blend?dl=0

Comment: it works fine, you need to put the second sphere at the exact same location (Alt G will put it), otherwise the rays won't hit any face

Comment: @moonboots nvm for late reply, for some reason its still baking so can't confirm. I literally didn't considered the "put the small sphere inside the big one" a big thing. I also saw this on a tutorial. Thanks for the time and help, hopefully it will work this time.

Comment: what do you mean by: "for some reason its still baking"?

Comment: @moonboots ig it gotta be something with my gtx 1050 ti. Its not that powerfull you know :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works fine, you need to put the second sphere at the exact same location (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> will put it), otherwise the rays won't hit any normal, or won't do it the way you expect.

Here is how baking works: the rays of the baking object are going in the opposite direction to this object's normals, and they will save all the original object's normals that they will meet:

[image]

If the 2 objects are not at the same location, the rays (if the *Ray Distance* is high enough, or set to 0) will hit some normals but it won't give the result you want:

[image]

Comment: it worked perfectly fine. I actually didn't knew also this concept of placing both obj in same place. Thanks again for help!